# Error when building Qt Application: /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: c++, qt, mingw32, build-error

I try to build my Qt application using these commands:

```
qmake -recursive external.pro
make
```

But it fails with this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [sub-bzip2-1-0-5-bzip2-1-0-5-pro-make_first] Error 2
```

Why am I getting this error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When you install Qt, make sure you take an installer windows for mingw (e.g  qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482_opengl-5.3.0.exe) and during the installation, check if it detect your mingw installation (specially your make.exe binary).
Qt need to patch your binary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but in my case it was because I had added Cygwin's bin directory to PATH in Windows:

[image]

Removing it fixed the error (you also **need to restart Qt Creator** so it refreshes its environment variables).

Comment: Happened me after adding Git to path and removing as you stated in the answer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem

The problem was resolved by renaming the project folder

> Project1210(2018-03-26) -> Project1210